# Increase space between axis.title and axis.text in ggplot2 (version >= 0.9.0)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently using the latest version of ggplot2 from github.

In version 0.8.9 I could do the following to increase space between axis.title and axis.text:

Before:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) + geom_bar() + opts(
    axis.title.x = theme_text(vjust=-1.1)
)
```

[image]

Fix:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) + geom_bar() + opts(
    axis.title.x = theme_text(vjust=-1.1),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0.8, 0.5), "lines")
)
```

[image: link to graph]

and the axis.title becomes fully visible.

In the latest github version of ggplot2 plot.margin has no effect on axis.title:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) + geom_bar() + opts(
    axis.title.x = theme_text(vjust=-0.2),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 0.5), "lines"))
```

[image: link to graph]

*(notice the increased bottom margin - I can't get plot.background to work in the latest development version)*

It seems that 0.8.9 allows axis.title to move over the extra space created by plot.margin, but this is not allowed in the latest development version.

Is there a new way to accomplish this task (or a quick fix for it) in the latest development version?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Adding the pictures was much appreciated, however if I edit my post to add additional information I am not allowed to save it unless i revert back to using links.

Comment: I put the figures back in. If you don't get a response here in reasonable time, try the ggplot2 or ggplot2-dev list, both hosted at google groups.

Comment: It would be useful if you could file this as a bug, or mention it on the ggplot2-dev mailing list.

Comment: @hadley I added a bug report with the quick fix, but linked to here for details - hope that's alright.

Comment: This has been changed in the last version, you should use the following instead `theme(axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(20,0,0,0)))`, go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487188/increase-distance-between-text-and-title-on-the-y-axis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am closing the question as the fix I made seems to hold for now (see below).

I found the following code in plot-render.r:64:

```
xlab_height <- grobHeight(xlabel) + 
  if (is.null(labels$x)) unit(0, "lines") else unit(0.5, "lines")
plot_table <- gtable_add_rows(plot_table, xlab_height)
plot_table <- gtable_add_grob(plot_table, xlabel, name = "xlab", 
  l = panel_dim$l, r = panel_dim$r, t = -1)

ylab_width <- grobWidth(ylabel) + 
  if (is.null(labels$y)) unit(0, "lines") else unit(0.5, "lines")
plot_table <- gtable_add_cols(plot_table, ylab_width, pos = 0)
plot_table <- gtable_add_grob(plot_table, ylabel, name = "ylab",
  l = 1, b = panel_dim$b, t = panel_dim$t)
```

which I changed to:

```
xlab_height <- grobHeight(xlabel) + 
  if (is.null(labels$x)) unit(0, "lines") else unit(0.5, "lines")
plot_table <- gtable_add_rows(plot_table, xlab_height)
plot_table <- gtable_add_grob(plot_table, xlabel, name = "xlab", 
  l = panel_dim$l, r = panel_dim$r, t = -1, clip = "off") <---- here

ylab_width <- grobWidth(ylabel) + 
  if (is.null(labels$y)) unit(0, "lines") else unit(0.5, "lines")
plot_table <- gtable_add_cols(plot_table, ylab_width, pos = 0)
plot_table <- gtable_add_grob(plot_table, ylabel, name = "ylab",
  l = 1, b = panel_dim$b, t = panel_dim$t, clip = "off") <---- here
```

This allows one to use the hjust/vjust combined with plot.margin to move the axis.titles without clipping.

On request I filled this a bug on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/407).

Answer (score 15):

### How to do it properly

Use the `margin` attribute of `element_text` for `axis.title` in `theme`.
I use different margins for x and y since I rotate the y title to horizontal (making it easier to read).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) +
    geom_bar() +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm"), angle = 0)
    )
```

[image: Demo of axis title margin]

### Old hack

`opts` and `theme_text` are no longer supported by ggplot. My quick and dirty solution is therefore to just add line breaks at the start or end of the title. It might be ugly but gets the job done with a minimal effort.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) +
    geom_bar() +
    xlab("\nClarity") + ylab("Count\n")
```

Comment: @branchwarren There's a yet another and more proper way to do it that was missing in both answers. Added it now.