# Increase distance between text and title on the y-axis

Tags: r, layout, plot, ggplot2

The y-axis title appears too close to the axis text.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot output]

I have tried changing the value of many parameters with `theme()` but none seems to help.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

From `ggplot2 2.0.0` you can use the `margin =` argument of `element_text()` to change the distance between the axis title and the numbers. Set the values of the `margin` on `t`op, `r`ight, `b`ottom, and `l`eft side of the element.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

---

`margin` can also be used for other `element_text` elements (see `?theme`), such as `axis.text.x`, `axis.text.y` and `title`.

**addition**

in order to set the margin for axis titles when the axis has a different position (e.g., with `scale_x_...(position = "top")`, you'll need a different theme setting - e.g. `axis.title.x.top`. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4343.

Comment: This method does not seem to work with `facet_grid`, whereas the answer suggested by Adam B does  (i.e. a line break using \n)

Comment: @Anonymous Can you give an example where this `margin =` argument doesn't wokr?

Comment: I tried it with `theme_bw`. Sorry, posting the whole code is unreadable / messy...

Comment: @Anonymous If you use `theme_bw()` then `theme_bw()` should be used before `theme()` function because in predefinied themes there is allready argument for axis titles.

Comment: How can I know which theme is in use? `plot2 <- ggplot(data=trans_by_month, aes(x=Month, y=AbsAmount, colour=NetAmount)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t=0,r=100,b=0,l=0))) +
  xlab(label="\nMonth") + ylab(label="\nTotal transaction value") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year)` has no effect, so I guess another theme is in use?

Comment: My comment only applies when using ggplotly. Using print() the margin method above has effect.

Comment: Didzis, I allowed myself to add the information about failing with different axis positions, into the answer rather than as a comment - for better visibility. Hope this is alright for you

Answer (score 139):

Based on this forum post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/mK9DR3dKIBU

Sounds like the easiest thing to do is to add a line break (\n) before your x axis, and after your y axis labels. Seems a lot easier (although dumber) than the solutions posted above.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    xlab("\nYour_x_Label") + ylab("Your_y_Label\n")
```

Comment: I usually use this method, it's much faster and it doesn't require to add yet another option to ggplot unless I need some specific tweaking.

Comment: this is great unless a legend is added. Then, the space is also reflected there

Comment: You can edit the legend text independently, but you’re right that by default it adds the new line to the legend.

Answer (score 11):

A solution that offers more fine-grained control than `\n` but is less cumbersome than adding margins is to use `vjust` in the `theme` function.

For adjusting the position on the y-axis or x-axis to add space, this often requires using a *positive value* for `vjust` (y-axis) or a negative value for `vjust` (x-axis) as in `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 2))`. See a fully worked example below.

```
# load patchwork to show plots side-by-side
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

# Plot A: just for comparison, moving titles *inward*
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_gray() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = -3),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = +3)
  ) 

# Plot B: what we want, moving titles *outward*
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_gray() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = +3),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.75)
  ) 

# show plots side-by-side with patchwork package
p1 + p2 +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the margin argument suggested by Didzis Elferts did not work for me. So, I used a different hack that is more flexible than adding an empty line but needs giving up the axis ticks.

```
myplot + theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length.x = unit(3.25, "cm")
```

I guess, one can add the tick marks manually with `geom_segment`. Another possibility might be  `[ggalt::annotation_ticks][1]`but I didn't bother trying either (note the current version of ggalt on CRAN (0.4) does not support this function, the one on github (0.6) does).