# R: ggplot and plotly axis margin won't change

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm having problems stopping the y-axis text from overlapping with the ticks using `ggplotly` around `ggplot`. How can I fix this? I've tried the following code:

[image]

```
set.seed(395)
df1<- data.frame(CO2= c(cumsum(rnorm(1*36)), cumsum(rnorm(1*36))),
                  Group= rep(c("A","B"), each=36),
                  Segment=rep(seq(1,12),each=36))

plot<-ggplot(df1, aes(CO2, fill = Group)) +
           geom_density(alpha = 0.8)+
           facet_wrap(~ Segment)+
           theme_bw()+
           labs(x="CO2", y="density")
#Shouldn't the following work?
    pb <- plotly_build(plot)
    pb$layout$margin$l <- 200
    pb$layout$margin$b <- 100
    pb
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487188/increase-distance-between-text-and-title-on-the-y-axis ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference. I should clarify I'm using ggplotly

Comment: I am getting `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found` for the `ggplot` call.

Comment: you example does not work; I have you tried something like pb  %>% 
  layout(margin = list(t=150, l = 150, r =150, b=150))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's use a simple reproducible example from [here](http://karawoo.com/2015-04-27-wsu/syllabus/ggplot2.html).

```
library(gapminder)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()
p <- p + aes(color=continent) + facet_wrap(~year)
gp <- ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

We can move the adjust the [margins](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-margin) as suggested by MLavoie but then our axis legend moves as well.

```
gp %>% layout(margin = list(l = 75))
```

[image]

The axis label is actually not a label but an annotation, so let's move it first. You can query the structure of the annotations in the graph `gp`:

```
# find the annotation you want to move
str(gp[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']]) 

List of 15
 $ :List of 13
  ..$ text          : chr "gdpPercap"
  ..$ x             : num 0.5
  ..$ y             : num -0.0294
  ..$ showarrow     : logi FALSE
  ..$ ax            : num 0
  ..$ ay            : num 0
  ..$ font          :List of 3
  .. ..$ color : chr "rgba(0,0,0,1)"
  .. ..$ family: chr ""
  .. ..$ size  : num 14.6
  ..$ xref          : chr "paper"
  ..$ yref          : chr "paper"
  ..$ textangle     : num 0
  ..$ xanchor       : chr "center"
  ..$ yanchor       : chr "top"
  ..$ annotationType: chr "axis"
 $ :List of 13
  ..$ text          : chr "lifeExp"
  ..$ x             : num -0.0346
  ..$ y             : num 0.5
.... <truncated>
```

Ok, so annotations are stored in a list of 15; "lifeExp" is the **second**(`[[2]]`) element of this list. The "x" (`[['x']]`) and "y" values control the movement left and right/up and down in this case, respectively.

```
# Check current x-location of x-axis label
gp[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[2]][['x']]
[1] -0.03459532

# Move the label further to the left
gp[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[2]][['x']] <- -0.1
gp %>% layout(margin = list(l = 75))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works a treat! Do you have any references for this code or documentation? Is it a plotly thing or a ggplot feature you are tweaking?

Comment: @HCAI: glad it worked! margins is a plotly layout attribute (I added a link to the original answer), the 2nd part is a tweak/hack of the ggplot to plotly conversion result. The conversion usually works pretty nice but sometimes it needs a bit help.

Comment: When I try this I get:  Error in `*tmp*`[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @MichaelSzczepaniak: I just tried it again and the code still works for me. Can you post your code and setup as a separate question?

Comment: @Max: Thx for the reply. I posted another question with code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523919/converting-ggplot-object-to-plotly-object-creates-axis-title-that-overlaps-tick

Comment: @Nova: Thanks for the suggested edit. In cases like this, i.e. substantial edits, feel free to add another answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I liked your answer - thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 5):

Find an answer from [Github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1224) that solved this problem elegantly.

```
layout_ggplotly <- function(gg, x = -0.02, y = -0.08){
  # The 1 and 2 goes into the list that contains the options for the x and y axis labels respectively
  gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[1]][['y']] <- x
  gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[2]][['x']] <- y
  gg
}
gp %>% layout_ggplotly
```

Answer (score 2):

I found both answers above quite useful. However, I noticed that the `layout_ggplotly()` function given above works correctly only when x and y axis titles exist. If either of those is missing -- for example, as a result of `theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())` -- then positional reference using `...[[1]]...` and `...[[2]]...` refers to wrong titles / annotations.

I wrote a function that I used in my project to address such limitation, I believe this builds up on the previous answers.

```
annotatify <- function(gg, x.y = -0.05, y.x = -0.05) {
  wip <- gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']] %>% 
    enframe() %>%
    mutate(value = map(value, as_tibble)) %>% 
    unnest(cols = c(value)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(annotationType)) %>% 
    mutate(
      x = case_when(x == 0.5 ~ x, TRUE ~ x.y),
      y = case_when(y == 0.5 ~ y, TRUE ~ y.x)
    ) %>% 
    select(name, text, x, y) %>% 
    unique()

  if (nrow(wip) == 2) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(wip)) {
      if (wip$x[i] == 0.50) {
        gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[1]][['y']] <- wip$y[i]
      } else {
        gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[2]][['x']] <- wip$x[i]
      }
    }
  } else if (wip$y == 0.5) {
    gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[1]][['x']] <- wip$x
  } else {
    gg[['x']][['layout']][['annotations']][[1]][['y']] <- wip$y
  }

  gg
}
```