# How to prevent x axes overlap ggplotly with facet_wrap(~variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have some data that looks nice when plotted with ggpglot but the x-axes and the plots underneath overlap in `plotly::ggplotly()`.

```
library(gapminder)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()
p <- p + aes(color=continent) + facet_wrap(~year,scale="free")
gp <- ggplotly(p)
gp
```

So I've been trying this: [R: ggplot and plotly axis margin won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763280/r-ggplot-and-plotly-axis-margin-wont-change)

Basically I need to increase the white space between each graph object and the one below. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add vertical space in between your facets using:

```
theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "line"))   # adjust to taste
```

However, there's a snag related to axis titles and facets when converting to plotly, where the axis title becomes an annotation and needs to be shifted more manually.

See these links for ways how:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228372/6851825

[Converting ggplot object to plotly object creates axis title that overlaps tick values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523919/converting-ggplot-object-to-plotly-object-creates-axis-title-that-overlaps-tick)

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1224

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the useful links!