# ggplot2: How to adjust spacing between plot area and axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I adjust (increase or decrease) space between the axis text (numbers) and the plot area (grey area)?

```
dfr <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5)
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

[image: fig]

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2) might be helpful.

Comment: See [Increase distance between text and title on the y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487188/increase-distance-between-text-and-title-on-the-y-axis). Just replace `axis.title.y` with `axis.text.y`.

Comment: Yep! That seems to be the right solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option could be using the `axis.ticks.length()` for setting the space between the plot area and axis text, as you have chosen not to display the ticks (`axis.ticks=element_blank()`).

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
    theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.length = unit(.85, "cm"),
          axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

It produces the output:

[image]

Alternatively, you can define the parameters(t,r,b,l) of the `margin()` to [adjust the space](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1502).

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)),
        axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 20)))
```

[image]

Comment: hacky solution! I am surprised there are no proper arguments to adjust this.

Comment: There should be a proper solution to do this but I could not find them easily. Hope to hear some other better solutions from others!