# ggplot2: Adjust distance between text and axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

As a followup to the question of how to
[Increase distance between text and title on the y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487188/increase-distance-between-text-and-title-on-the-y-axis), I am wondering whether it is also possible to adjust the distance between an *axis* and its title/label. This could be useful for creating similarly styled graphs, for example when the tick marks of two graphs are of different magnitudes.

Here are two example plots:

```
plot_a <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()
plot_b <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy*100)) + geom_point()
```

Note the difference on the left side of the plots:

[image]

[image]

Cowplot can, somehow, do the job and set the distance of *axis* and *label* the same in two plots:

```
cowplot::plot_grid (plotlist = list (plot_a, plot_b),
                align = "v",
                nrow = 2,
                ncol = 1,
                greedy = T)
```

[image]

However, I'd rather like to adjust the distance bewteen the label and the axis manually. Also, there are cases where it's preferable to draw one single plot per panel, rendering the `cowplot`-solution useless. So - is there a possibility to manually adjust the distance between axis and label?

Comment: which package does `opts` originate from? It just gives me `Error in opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(vjust = -0.5)) : 
  could not find function "opts"`

Comment: sorry, it is changed to `theme`

Comment: Now I get `Error in theme_text(vjust = -0.5) : could not find function "theme_text"` - I suppose this might have changed, also? When I use `element_text`, I face the same problem as with @Didzis Elferts proposal to use `margin`: it is not consistent among plots with differing axis text length.

Comment: Have you considered using patchwork to create a range of aligned plots? See: https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork.  You could simply cheat by appending "\n " to axis titles, prepending " \n" to x-axis text and appending "\t" to y-axis text.

Comment: patchwork (of which I had never heard before) is, indeed, very interesting. However, my goal is not to combine separate plots into the same graphic. I rather want to produce *separate* plots with identical properties. Like "figure 1", which could be a barchart and "figure 2" which could be a scatterplot. In a final document, both figures should appear on different pages, however, I'd like them to have exactly the same appereance. With the 'cowplot' example I just wanted to show that it somehow must be possible to adjust the distance betwee axis and label on different plots in the same manner.

Comment: I could also put it the other way round: is there a reproducible way to get the result of the 'cowplot'-example as two *separate* graphics?